# Data Cleaning: processing extra if statements vs performing extra assignments

Tags: sas

EDIT: I see why this is the wrong way to go about it (and I was forgetting how I have even done this in the past) and have accepted Joe's answer.  I would still be interested if anyone has any comments to add on performance considerations in SAS on comparing more if statements vs performing extra assignments.

---

Which of these methods is preferred?

When cleaning some data by combining several variants/typos into a single correct value,
I could do this:

### Option A:

```
if value in (
    'A: Wrong Value 1'
    'A: Typo 1'
    'a: Typo 2'
    'A: Wrong Value 2'
  ) then value = 'A: Correct Value';
else if value in (
    'B: Wrong Value 1'
    'B: Wrong Value 2'
    'B: Typo 1'
  ) then value = 'B: Correct Value';
else if value in (
    'C: Wrong Value 1'
    'C: Wrong Value 2'
    'C: Wrong Value 3'
    'C: Typo 1'
  ) then value = 'C: Correct Value';
**etc.  Assume there are a bunch of similar statements;
**with any number of items on the "in" list;
```

The problem I see with these operations are that every time you come across 'A: Correct Value', you will have to process it through every if statement.  It's not a huge deal, but it feels wrong to me that something from group "A" will still be running through all  tests down to group "Z".

So instead, I could write it:

### Option B

```
if value in (
    'A: Correct Value'
    'A: Wrong Value 1'
    'A: Typo 1'
    'a: Typo 2'
    'A: Wrong Value 2'
  ) then value = 'A: Correct Value';
else if value in (
    'B: Correct Value'
    'B: Wrong Value 1'
    'B: Wrong Value 2'
    'B: Typo 1'
  ) then value = 'B: Correct Value';
else if value in (
    'C: Correct Value'
    'C: Wrong Value 1'
    'C: Wrong Value 2'
    'C: Wrong Value 3'
    'C: Typo 1'
  ) then value = 'C: Correct Value';
```

This stops it from evaluating past the proper group (and has the added advantage of allowing you to add something like `else value = 'Not Cleaned';` at the end).

However, this version ends up doing the equivalent of `if value = 'A: Correct Value' then value = 'A: Correct Value';`. This seems like a wasteful operation although it is possibly less wasteful than carrying on checking the if statements.

So far I have:

- **Option A**

  - Pros:

    - Shorter Code
    - Only reassigns incorrect values (no `if a = 1 then a = 1`)
  - Cons:

    - When a value doesn't need to be cleaned, it will have to continue through every if statement
    - Can't finish with an else clause
- **Option B**

  - Pros:

    - Evaluation stops at the right group for both clean and unclean values.
    - Can use an `else` clause to catch all uncleaned values (helpful if you update the underlying data and want to do something else with the new values)
    - "in" list contains all values that map to a single clean value (might be helpful if you were generating these programmatically)
  - Cons:

    - You have to do the `if a = 1 then a = 1` operation;
    - Slightly longer code since you have to write out the correct value twice.

My thought on this would be that option B is the better way to accomplish this.  Having access to the `else` statement and not having to send a clean "A: Correct Value" all the way through to the if statement for Z seems to outweigh any value of avoiding the `if a = 1 then a = 1` construct.  But I am not super familiar with the underlying activity that SAS does, so maybe the reassignment operation is more time consuming than checking through some extra if statements.

Comment: I suppose there is a third option too.  You could add an additional if statement that catches correct values and does nothing with them.  if this were the first if statement, and the majority of your data were clean, this would probably save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these options is a particularly good option for data cleaning.  Wallpaper coding, ie generating lots of `IF` statements, is highly inefficient, hard to read/maintain, and slow to write.  It also stores data in the program, which is undesirable; good programming habits separate data from code so that if your data changes, you simply modify the (other) data rather than modifying your program.

Single value data cleaning (ie, check ) is best done with formats.  You can write a format in your program if you prefer, but even better is to maintain that in a dataset (or excel sheet or database table or whatever else).

A simple format solution:

```
proc format;
value q01f
1-5  = [F1.0]
other= INVALID;
quit;

data test;
input x;
x_fixed = put(x,q01f.);
if put(x,Q01f.)='INVALID' then ; *take action here;
put x= x_fixed=;
datalines;
1
2
3
6
8
5
4
1
;;;;
run;
```

There, the values 1 through 5 are 'legal' and the other values are coded to "INVALID".  You can use that instead of your list of IF statements - and you get back the 'legal' value if it is legal on top of that.  Of course you can put something desired instead of 'INVALID'; if you want 99 to be the 'invalid' responses, then put 99 there.

This is not only very fast (faster than multiple IF statements or booleans) but it is easy to maintain.  Put those legal values and format names in an excel file.  Not only do you get an easy to maintain list of legal values (that could be maintained by a non-programmer), but you get a data dictionary free of charge.

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking clearly.  Usually what I would do here is have a "recode" dataset with one column that contains every unique value and a second column that contains the correct clean value for each...then I would sort by value and merge.  I'm not sure how your format solution works here.  I am trying to reassign the bad values (which are strings) to the cleaned value...so instead of 6=invalid, I'd want 6=5 (or 1 or whatever the correct value was).

Comment: You would have to be more detailed with your specific concern, but you certainly could establish a format like that.  If it's a direct recode, you could certainly do exactly that in a format.  Look up how to use the `cntlin` dataset with `proc format`; your initial value would be `start` and your recoded value `label`.

Comment: This is neat.  Won't require sorting a large dataset twice (once to the unclean value and a second time back to something useful).  One last question: at what point do you start having performance concerns with a large format?  If I have 10,000 messy values that clean up to 1000 correct values (in a 100,000 observation dataset), is SAS going to struggle with a format with 10k options? (not to say that I was going to have 1000 if statements...just thinking about the future here)

Comment: Depends on memory; I think a few hundred thousand would be okay, but millions might start to be an issue, on a standard 2GB RAM desktop.  If you're on a server with tons of RAM, you're reasonably safe.